# CompileError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors, arm

I am getting the error below when executing this code:

```
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_MCP9808.MCP9808 as MCP9808
import json;

sensor = MCP9808.MCP9808()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/sensor01.py", line 17, in <module>
    sensor = MCP9808.MCP9808()`enter code here`
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_MCP9808/MCP9808.py", line 62, in __init__
    import Adafruit_GPIO.I2C as I2C
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 25, in <module>
    import smbus
  File "/home/pi/smbus/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .smbus import ffi
  File "/home/pi/smbus/smbus.py", line 94, in <module>
    """, ext_package='smbus')
  File "/home/pi/smbus/cffi/api.py", line 433, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "/home/pi/smbus/cffi/verifier.py", line 113, in load_library
    self._compile_module()
  File "/home/pi/smbus/cffi/verifier.py", line 210, in _compile_module
    outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
  File "/home/pi/smbus/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 29, in compile
    outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose)
  File "/home/pi/smbus/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 62, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
VerificationError: CompileError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was permissions issues - when trying to install setup.py.
This post helped me fix the issues:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/create-file-in-folder-permission-denied